# How to download image using Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am newbie to scrapy. I am trying to download an image from [here](http://www.shopclues.com/canon-powershot-sx410-is-2.html). I was following [Official-Doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html) and [this article](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/12/scraping-images-with-python-and-scrapy/).

My settings.py looks like:

```
BOT_NAME = 'shopclues'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['shopclues.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'shopclues.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline':1
}

IMAGES_STORE="home/pr.singh/Projects"
```

and `items.py` looks like:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item

class ShopcluesItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    pass

class ImgData(Item):
    image_urls=scrapy.Field()
    images=scrapy.Field()
```

I think both these files are good. But I am unable to write correct spider for getting the image. I am able to grab the image URL but don't know how to store image using `imagePipeline`.
My spider looks like:

```
from shopclues.items import ImgData
import scrapy
import datetime


class DownloadFirstImg(scrapy.Spider):
    name="DownloadfirstImg"
    start_urls=[
    'http://www.shopclues.com/canon-powershot-sx410-is-2.html',
    ]

    def parse (self, response):
        url= response.css("body div.site-container div#container div.ml_containermain div.content-helper div.aside-site-content div.product form#product_form_83013851 div.product-gallery div#product_images_83013851_update div.slide a#det_img_link_83013851_25781870")

        yield scrapy.Request(url.xpath('@href').extract(),self.parse_page)

        def parse_page(self,response):
            imgURl=response.css("body div.site-container div#container div.ml_containermain div.content-helper div.aside-site-content div.product form#product_form_83013851 div.product-gallery div#product_images_83013851_update div.slide a#det_img_link_83013851_25781870::attr(href)").extract()

            yield {
            ImgData(image_urls=[imgURl])
            }
```

I have written the spider following [this-article](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/12/scraping-images-with-python-and-scrapy/). But I am not getting anything. I run my spider as `scrapy crawl DownloadfirstImg  -o img5.json`
 but I am not getting any json nor any image?
  Any help on How to grab image if it's url is known. I have never worked with python also so things seem much complicated to me. Links to any good tutorial may help. TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you yield a request for an image you just need to save it on the item and the images pipeline will do the rest, this is all you need.

```
def parse (self, response):
    url= response.css("body div.site-container div#container div.ml_containermain div.content-helper div.aside-site-content div.product form#product_form_83013851 div.product-gallery div#product_images_83013851_update div.slide a#det_img_link_83013851_25781870")
    yield ImgData(image_urls=[url.xpath('@href').extract_first()])
```

Comment: Great, that worked within seconds. Even I was confused what I was doing, not so sure about how all this works. Can you provide links to some good tutorials other than their documentation. Also, this code worked for first time, after I deleted the image and tried again I am getting `Spider error processing <GET http://www.shopclues.com/canon-powershot-sx410-is-2.html> (referer: None)` ? What could be the possible reason? BTW, thanks for help :)

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh After that error occurs the traceback tells you what's wrong. What is the last line of the error?

Comment: Forget it. I was having a corrupted file in the directory, deleted that one and everything worked fine. I couldn't debug my code because even I din't know what I wrote, my code was just kind of copy-paste. Are there good tutorials/blogs available to begin with (other than their documentation)? Thanks BTW.

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh http://mherman.org/blog/2012/11/05/scraping-web-pages-with-scrapy/#.V-ziSnUrJhE this one is a personal favorite